# Body load and jquery problem

Tags: jquery

There is a div:

```
<div id="question">ddddd</div>
```

I have written a code that hide the other div:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {
             $('div#dialog').hide();
             $('div#question').click(function() 
                {
                  $('div#dialog').show('slow');

                    return false;

                }
        );

     $('a.kapat').click(function() 
        {

             $('.frm').hide('slow');

            return false;

        }
     ); 
     });
```

Every thing work perfect, but when page loading, the "div#dialog" is open. How can I fix this? I want to that "div#dialog" be hidden when page loading.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `<div>` hidden with css to begin with.

Then instead of using **hide** and **show** use **toggle**.

Comment: Just add style="display:none;" to your DIV tag.